After migration to SharePoint 2019 on premise we are getting deprecated errors in console. How to resolve it?
We have recently migrated to SharePoint 2019 on premise and getting deprecated errors in console of browser. Please help us to remove these errors.


These are deprecated features for the future versions of Chrome or Edge with Chromium. A fix is planned for SharePoint SE, but not for SharePoint 2016 and 2019.
Check this article for more information: JavaScript mutation events deprecation in Chrome and Edge and impact on SharePoint Server

The issue itself does not impact any product functionality. A fix for
SharePoint Server Subscription Edition is currently in the works. I
will update this blog post when a fix is available.
Be aware that there is no currently no plan to release a fix for this
issue for SharePoint Server 2016 and SharePoint Server 2019 as these
products are in extended support and this issue doesn’t block the
product functionality.

